# Error linking cv::ximproc library to project

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ximgproc;
```

Function of class stereo:

```
 void stereo_matcher::cpu_sgbm_matcher(cv::Mat& IL, cv::Mat& IR, int min_disp, int max_disp)
    {
        int cn = IL.channels();
    int winsize =9; //3

//    Ptr<StereoSGBM> sgbm = StereoSGBM::create(0,256,9,0,0,1,63);
     Ptr<StereoSGBM> left_matcher = StereoSGBM::create(0,max_disp,winsize);

    left_matcher->setPreFilterCap(63);
    left_matcher->setBlockSize(winsize);
    left_matcher->setP1(8*cn*winsize*winsize); //8
    left_matcher->setP2(32*cn*winsize*winsize); //32
    left_matcher->setMinDisparity(min_disp);
    left_matcher->setNumDisparities(max_disp);
    left_matcher->setUniquenessRatio(10);
    left_matcher->setSpeckleWindowSize(100);
    left_matcher->setSpeckleRange(32);
    left_matcher->setDisp12MaxDiff(1);
    left_matcher->setMode(StereoSGBM::MODE_HH);

    left_matcher->compute(IL, IR, disp16L);

   Ptr<StereoMatcher> right_matcher = createRightMatcher(left_matcher);

    right_matcher->compute(IR, IL, disp16R);

//    cout<<disp16L<<endl;

    Mat filtered_disp;
    Mat conf_map = Mat(IL.rows,IL.cols,CV_8U);
    conf_map = Scalar(255);
    Ptr<DisparityWLSFilter> wls_filter=createDisparityWLSFilter(left_matcher);
//    wls_filter = createDisparityWLSFilter(left_matcher);
    cout<<"Here§§"<<endl;
    wls_filter->setLambda(8000);

    wls_filter->setSigmaColor(1.5);


    double filtering_time = (double)getTickCount();
    wls_filter->filter(disp16L,IL,filtered_disp,disp16R);
    filtering_time = ((double)getTickCount() - filtering_time)/getTickFrequency();
    cout<<"Filtering time: "<<filtering_time<<"s"<<endl;


    disp16L=filtered_disp.clone();

    disp16L.convertTo(disp32F, CV_32F,(double)1.0/(16.0),0.0);

//    //! [visualization]
//    double vis_mult=1.0;
//    Mat raw_disp_vis;
//    cv::ximgproc::getDisparityVis(disp16L,raw_disp_vis,vis_mult);
//    namedWindow("raw disparity", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
//    imshow("raw disparity", raw_disp_vis);
//    Mat filtered_disp_vis;
//    cv::ximgproc::getDisparityVis(filtered_disp,filtered_disp_vis,vis_mult);
//    namedWindow("filtered disparity", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
//    imshow("filtered disparity", filtered_disp_vis);
//    waitKey(0);
//    //! [visualization]

}
```

What I did:
I'm following example found at:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/ximgproc/samples/disparity_filtering.cpp

I have installed Opencv extra modules from the procedures of:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib

Issues:
Even though my IDE(Qt) recognises the header file

## include

when I compile I get the following errors:
../../lib/libstereo.a(stereo_matcher.cpp.o): In function `stereo_matcher::cpu_sgbm_matcher(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int, int)':
stereo_matcher.cpp:(.text+0xcc9): undefined reference to`cv::ximgproc::createDisparityWLSFilter(cv::Ptr)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/test_stereo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [apps/CMakeFiles/test_stereo.dir/all] Error 2

How do I go about linking this library of OpenCV

Thanks in advance for helping out

Answer (score 1):

In Qt Creator I added to .pro file line `LIBS += -lopencv_ximgproc` and it helped me. (Qt 5.11, OpenCV 3.2, Linux Ubuntu 18.04)

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv
....
LIBS += -lopencv_ximgproc
```

You should have in your folder  `/usr/local/include/opencv` library file

```
libopencv_ximgproc.so
```